# How to remove the trailing comma & space in a for-each loop that generates links in a mvc vbhtml view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, vb.net, string-concatenation

Given a loop like:

```
  @For Each x In item.PostCategory
          Dim cats = x.CategoryName & ", "
          @Html.ActionLink(cats, 
         "PostsByCategory", "Posts", New With {.Category = x.CategoryName.ToSeoUrl, 
         .Page = Nothing}, Nothing) 
      Next
```

I need to remove only the **last comma and space** - everything I have tried removes the commas and spaces in the middle as well as the end. The loop renders categories and I want them separated by a comma and space but do not need or want the trailing comma and space. Each category needs to be a separate link so string.join won't work. I tried trim.substring - that removes the commas in the middle. TrimEnd did not work. I have searched and have not found a solution.

Instead of World, Science, - i want World, Science

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check if `x` is the last item in `PostCategory`. If it is true, then append an empty string, else append comma and space :

```
Dim cats = x.CategoryName  & IIf(x.Equals(item.PostCategory.Last()), "", ", ")
```

Comment: I get an error - `Operator '=' is not defined for types 'be_Categories' and 'be_Categories'

Answer (score 0):

There's many different ways to solve this problem. You'll have to determine the best way. Simply, you can just not use a foreach and do a simple for instead. Then you can easily tell if you're on the last item by comparing the index with the count and conditional show or not show the comma based on that.

Alternatively, you can construct a list of the string values this code would otherwise render directly to the page and then use `string.Join` to join the list items separated by `", "`. `string.Join` never appends the delimiter to the end, so that fixes your problem.

You could also go fancier with some sort of editor template or partial view or even create a `HtmlHelper` extension. If just depends on how you want to handle it.